# Fix Material-UI Right Side Persistent Drawer Animation

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have a fairly complex application with multiple drawers. I'm having an issue with the right side drawer animations. The drawers themselves animate fine, but the parent divs do not. I tried applying the same animation for the drawer to the parent div and this did not solve my problem. I've replicated the issue in CodeSandbox. See below.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/w36rxmvp8)

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, thanks for letting me know. Try this. https://codesandbox.io/embed/w36rxmvp8

Comment: What exactly problem did you mean? Black background during the animation?

Comment: Yep. In our application, the Canvas is a 2d/3d workspace and the parent div snaps to full-width while the drawer animates in. My current workaround is to make the parent div's background color the same as the Canvas' bg color.

Comment: What do you mean @RicardoCosta ? The animation in my example is using the default MUI CSS animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our specific use case is fairly complicated, but I think we've managed to find a fix. Essentially, we had to apply a transition to the `<main>` element and set its margin based on the state of the right toolbar. See below.

```
main: {
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginRight: -500,
  },
  mainRightOpen: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginRight: 0,
  }
```

and implemented like so...

```
<main
  className={`${classes.main}
    ${this.props.rightToolBarOpen ? classes.mainRightOpen : null}
   `}
  ref={(mainContent) => { this.mainContent = mainContent; }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want the fixed margin value, you may consider to use percentage for the margin control, for instance:

```
// define the drawerWidth

const drawerWidth = 33.33333;

// put margin value as a string format like below: 

content: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: theme.spacing(6),
  transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  marginRight: `${-drawerWidth}%`,
},
contentShift: {
  transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  marginRight: 0,
},
```

Above solution works form me (Material-UI version I am using: v4.12.1)